# csh line to wait for text line in file

Tags: while-loop, csh

I need to block a script using csh for a line to appear in a log file.

So far I have tried :

```
while ( ! grep 'run completes with' run.log )
  sleep 10
end
```

But I get 
    `while: Expression Syntax.`

Which is not the desired outcome. I tried with / without the `()` but no success.

I have seen solutions using `tail -f` but I don't like that many of them leave the tail process hanging in the end.

Is there a one-line (or few line) solution for this without tail?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`<snark>`Unlike most *real* shells (sh, bash, etc)`</snark>`, you need to use `{` and `}` if you want to use the success/failure status of a command as a condition.

This should work:

```
while ( ! { grep 'run completes with' run.log } )
  sleep 10
end
```

Consider using `grep -q` unless you actually want to see the output of the `grep` command.

(Note that this rescans the entire `run.log` file every 10 seconds, which could be a problem if it's very large.)

Comment: Obligatory link: http://web.mit.edu/ghudson/info/csh.whynot I used tcsh myself for many years until I switched to bash, which I find *much* better. tcsh has some nice interactive features, but modern versions of bash are about as good in that area.